# State and IO Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I've been trying to wrap my head around the concept of monads and I've been experimenting with the following example:

I have an `Editor` data-type that represents the state of a text document and some functions that work on it.

```
data Editor = Editor {
  lines :: [Line],    -- editor contents are kept line by line      
  lineCount :: Int,   -- holds length lines at all times
  caret :: Caret      -- the current caret position
  -- ... some more definitions
} deriving (Show)

-- get the line at the given position (first line is at 0)
lineAt :: Editor -> Int -> Line
lineAt ed n = ls !! n
  where
    ls = lines ed

-- get the line that the caret is currently on
currentLine :: Editor -> Line
currentLine ed = lineAt ed $ currentY ed

-- move the caret horizontally by the specified amount of characters (can not
-- go beyond the current line)
moveHorizontally :: Editor -> Int -> Editor
moveHorizontally ed n = ed { caret = newPos }
  where
    Caret x y = caret ed
    l = currentLine ed
    mx = fromIntegral (L.length l - 1)
    newX = clamp 0 mx (x+n)
    newPos = Caret newX y


-- ... and lots more functions to work with an Editor
```

All of these functions act on an `Editor`, and many of them return a new `Editor` (where the caret has been moved or some text has been changed) so I thought this might be a good application of the `State` monad and I have re-written most `Editor`-functions to now look like this:

```
lineAt' :: Int -> State Editor Line
lineAt' n = state $ \ed -> (lines ed !! n, ed)

currentLine' :: State Editor Line
currentLine' = do
  y <- currentY'
  lineAt' y

moveHorizontally' :: Int -> State Editor ()
moveHorizontally' n = do
  (Caret x y) <- gets caret
  l <- currentLine'
  let mx = fromIntegral (L.length l - 1)
  let newX = clamp 0 mx (x+n)
  modify (\ed -> ed { caret = Caret newX y })

moveHorizontally' :: Int -> State Editor ()
moveHorizontally' n = do
  (Caret x y) <- gets caret
  l <- currentLine'
  let mx = fromIntegral (L.length l - 1)
  let newX = clamp 0 mx (x+n)
  modify (\ed -> ed { caret = Caret newX y })
```

This is pretty awesome, because it allows me to compose editing actions very easily within `do`-notation.

However, now I'm struggling to put this to use within an actual application. Say I want to use this `Editor` within an application that performs some IO. Say I want to manipulate an instance of `Editor` everytime the user presses the `l` key on the keyboard.

I would need to have another `State` monad representing the overall application state that holds an `Editor` instance and a sort-of event-loop that uses the `IO` monad to read from the keyboard and calls `moveHorizontally'` to modify the current AppState by modifying its `Editor`.

I've read up a bit on this topic and it seems like I need to use **Monad Transformers** to build a stack of monads with IO at the bottom. I've never used Monad Transformers before and I don't know what to do from here? I've also found out that the `State` monad already implements some functionality (it seems to be a special case of a Monad Transformer?) but I'm confused on how to use that?

Comment: "All of these functions act on an Editor, and many of them return a new Editor (where the caret has been moved or some text has been changed)" --

This is a good thing! It is very unlikely that a plain IO loop applying your original pure functions would produce a new Editor in memory. GHC will copy the structure only when it needs to, and will update in-place if the old reference is not used. You don't necessarily need to use transformers here, and your code will be clearer without them.

Comment: @DeX3 FYI, submitting a *self-contained* post makes it a lot easier for people to write code to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's back up a bit. It's always best to have problems isolated. Let pure functions be grouped with pure functions, State - with State and IO - with IO. Intertwining multiple concepts is a certain recipe for cooking code-spaghetti. You don't want that meal.

Having said that, let's restore the pure functions that you had and group them in a module. However we'll apply small modifications to make them conform to the Haskell conventions - namely, we'll change the parameter order:

```
-- |
-- In this module we provide all the essential functions for 
-- manipulation of the Editor type.
module MyLib.Editor where

data Editor = ...

lineAt :: Int -> Editor -> Line

moveHorizontally :: Int -> Editor -> Editor
```

Now, if you really want to get your `State` API back, it's trivial to implement in another module:

```
-- |
-- In this module we address the State monad.
module MyLib.State where

import qualified MyLib.Editor as A

lineAt :: Int -> State A.Editor Line
lineAt at = gets (A.lineAt at)

moveHorizontally :: Int -> State A.Editor ()
moveHorizontally by = modify (A.moveHorizontally by)
```

As you see now, following the standard conventions allows us to use the standard `State` utilities like [`gets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#v:gets) and [`modify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#v:modify) to trivially lift the already implemented functions to the `State` monad.

However, actually the mentioned utilities work for the `StateT` monad-transformer as well, of which `State` is actually just a special case. So we can just as well implement the same thing in a more general way:

```
-- |
-- In this module we address the StateT monad-transformer.
module MyLib.StateT where

import qualified MyLib.Editor as A

lineAt :: Monad m => Int -> StateT A.Editor m Line
lineAt at = gets (A.lineAt at)

moveHorizontally :: Monad m => Int -> StateT A.Editor m ()
moveHorizontally by = modify (A.moveHorizontally by)
```

As you see, all that's changed are the type signatures.

Now you can use those general functions in your transformer stack. E.g.,

```
-- |
-- In this module we address the problems of the transformer stack.
module MyLib.Session where

import qualified MyLib.Editor as A
import qualified MyLib.StateT as B

-- | Your trasformer stack
type Session = StateT A.Editor IO

runSession :: Session a -> A.Editor -> IO (a, A.Editor)
runSession = runStateT

lineAt :: Int -> Session Line
lineAt = B.lineAt

moveHorizontally :: Int -> Session ()
moveHorizontally = B.moveHorizontally

-- |
-- A function to lift the IO computation into our stack.
-- Luckily for us it is already presented by the MonadIO type-class.
-- liftIO :: IO a -> Session a
```

Thus we've just achieved a granular isolation of concerns and a great flexibility of our codebase.

Now, of course, this makes a quite primitive example so far. Usually the final monad-transformer stack has more levels. E.g.,

```
type Session = ExceptT Text (ReaderT Database (StateT A.Editor IO))
```

To jump between all those levels the typical tool-set is [the `lift` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) or [the "mtl" library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl), which provides type-classes to reduce the usage of `lift`. I have to mention though, that not everyone (myself including) is a fan of "mtl", because, while reducing the amount of code it introduces a certain ambiguity and reasoning complexity. I prefer to use `lift` explicitly.

The point of transformers is to allow you to extend an existing monad (transformer stack is a monad as well) with some new functionality in an ad-hoc way.

As for your question about extending the app's state, you can simply add another StateT layer to your stack:

```
-- |
-- In this module we address the problems of the transformer stack.
module MyLib.Session where

import qualified MyLib.Editor as A
-- In presence of competing modules,
-- it's best to rename StateT to the more specific EditorStateT
import qualified MyLib.EditorStateT as B
import qualified MyLib.CounterStateT as C

-- | Your trasformer stack
type Session = StateT Int (StateT A.Editor IO)

lineAt :: Int -> Session Line
lineAt = lift B.lineAt

moveHorizontally :: Int -> Session ()
moveHorizontally = lift B.moveHorizontally

-- | An example of addressing a different level of the stack.
incCounter :: Session ()
incCounter = C.inc

-- | An example of how you can dive deeply into your stack.
liftIO :: IO a -> Session a
liftIO io = lift (lift io)
```

Comment: Alright, that helped a great deal. I understood steps 1 & 2 and cleaned up my code accordingly. However I'm still a little confused by how it all comes together at the end. As a starting point, what exactly does the type signature `moveHorizontally :: Monad m => Int -> StateT A.Editor m ()` convey?


`moveHorizontally` is a function taking an `Int` and returning a StateTransformer where the state is an `A.Editor` and the immediate return value is some `Monad` holding the empty type (because `moveHorizontally` just modifies state but doesn't have any immediate result)? Is that right?

Comment: You are confusing `StateT a m b` with `State a (m b)`. They are different things. `State a b` is equivalent to the `a -> (b, a)` function. So, `State a (m b)` is equivalent this function: `a -> (m b, a)`. `StateT a m b`, on the other hand, is equivalent to `a -> m (b, a)`. [The Hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#t:StateT) should help you clear things out a bit. Also I have [an article training the intuition into `State`](https://nikita-volkov.github.io/a-taste-of-state-parsers-are-easy/) using parsers.

Comment: yep, you're right - I confused `State` with `StateT` there. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Session` is basically a "bigger" Application State, right? What if I wanted to add more stateful properties to it that are not really suitable for putting them into the `Editor` (for example, some counter that keeps track of how many times the user has pressed a key or something similar)?

Comment: `mtl`'s `MonadIO` class has relatively little ambiguity potential, since `IO` is *always* at the bottom. It's a very convenient class as well.

Comment: @dfeuer It's not from "mtl", though, but from "transformers". Also, AFAIK it made it to the "base" package recently. "mtl" does export a class, which I find very useful - `MonadError`.

Comment: Oh, you're right! It felt so `mtl`-ish that I figured it was. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) you won't need to commit to any monad stack in particular until the point of your program where you actually run the effects. This means that you can easily change the stack to add extra layers, pick a different error-reporting strategy, etc., etc.

All you need to do is enable the `-XFlexibleContexts` language extension by adding the following line at the top of your file:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

Import the module defining the `MonadState` class:

```
import Control.Monad.State
```

Change the type annotation of your programs to reflect the fact that you are now using this approach. The `MonadState Editor m =>` constraints says that `m` is a monad which has a state of type `Editor` somewhere in it.

```
lineAt'      :: MonadState Editor m => Int -> m Line
currentY'    :: MonadState Editor m => m Int
currentLine' :: MonadState Editor m => m Line
```

Let's say that you now want to read a line from `stdin` and push it onto the list of lines (in practice you'd probably want to insert the characters after the current carret and move it accordingly but the general idea is the same). You can simply use the `MonadIO` constraint to indicate that you need some `IO` capability for this function:

```
newLine :: (MonadIO m, MonadState Editor m) => m ()
newLine = do
  nl <- liftIO getLine
  modify $ \ ed -> ed { lines = nl : lines ed }
```

Comment: How do you runState with newLine? can we do `runState newLine editor`?

Comment: @vdj4y You'd want to use `runStateT` and that should produce a `MonadIO m => m ((), editor)`